# How to define a property as optional

Tags: json, class, properties

I have the following class

```
    Private Class OCOOrderRecord
        Public Property orderListId As Integer
        Public Property contingencyType As String
        Public Property listStatusType As String
        Public Property listOrderStatus As String
        Public Property listClientOrderId As String
        Public Property transactionTime As Long
        Public Property symbol As String
        Public Property orders As List(Of OrdersRecord)
        Public Property orderReports As List(Of OrderReportsRecord)
    End Class

    Private Class OrdersRecord
        Public Property symbol As String
        Public Property orderId As Integer
        Public Property clientOrderId As String
    End Class

    Private Class OrderReportsRecord
        Public Property symbol As String
        Public Property orderId As Integer
        Public Property orderListId As Integer
        Public Property clientOrderId As String
        Public Property transactTime As Long
        Public Property price As String
        Public Property origQty As String
        Public Property executedQty As String
        Public Property cummulativeQuoteQty As String
        Public Property status As String
        Public Property timeInForce As String
        Public Property type As String
        Public Property side As String
        Public Property stopPrice As String
    End Class
```

The JSON response that I receive has two items in orderReports property. The first one contains a stopPrice value but the second one no. So I fail to parse it correctly. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I did it by editing the response and adding an empty value for stopPrice property